# Add an empty div on a certain index of a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm passing in an array of product items via a computed variable in to a collection item component on a collection page. After the third product I'd like there to be an empty collection item, ie. a collection item template but with no product content inside. If anyone would have any ideas how I could achieve this in Vue.js I'd be most grateful.

```
collection page:

        <collection-item
          v-for="product in products" 
          :collection-item="product"
        ></collection-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap your `<collection-item` inside a template, and `v-for` loop that, then add a `v-if` condition onto your `collection-item`

```
<template>
  <section>
    <template v-for="(row, index) in rows">
      <collection v-if="index !== 3" :key="index"></collection>
      <div v-else :key="index">something else if needed or remove</div>
    </template>
  </section>
</template>
```

codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-wood-qglqe?file=/pages/index.vue:0-216

Answer (score 1):

If you know it will always be the third product that you want this empty item after, then you could loop on an outer container (like `template`, [which acts as an invisible wrapper element in Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt)) instead of `collection-item`, and use a `v-if` in conjunction with the [`index` property available from `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for) (second example on the Vue docs at the link).

```html
<template v-for="(product, index) in products">
    <collection-item :collection-item="product" />
    <collection-item v-if="index == 2" />
</template>
```

Alternatively, you could splice an empty product into your array at the third position programmatically, which would ultimately have the same result, but may not be as clear as adding it in the template if it's purely for visual reasons.

As a final note, whenever you use v-for on a custom component, you *must* (since Vue v2.2.0) include a `key` property to help Vue distinguish between the list elements it renders. This should be something unique to all elements, like a `product.id`, but the `index` can work as a last resort too, if it doesn't cause problems.